# PHP: bool vs boolean type hinting

Tags: php, boolean, default-value, type-hinting

I've been trying to use type hinting more in PHP. Today I was writing a function that takes a boolean with a default parameter and I noticed that a function of the form

```
function foo(boolean $bar = false) {
    var_dump($bar);
}
```

actually throws a fatal error:

> Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL

While a function of the similar form

```
function foo(bool $bar = false) {
    var_dump($bar);
}
```

does not. However, both

```
var_dump((bool) $bar);
var_dump((boolean) $bar);
```

give the exact same output

> :boolean false

Why is this? Is this similar to the wrapper classes in Java?

Comment: check the **valid supported types** at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: use `bool` for type hinting.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.base.scalar

> **Warning**
> Aliases for the above scalar types are not supported. Instead, they are treated as class or interface names. For example, using boolean as a parameter or return type will require an argument or return value that is an instanceof the class or interface boolean, rather than of type bool:

> ```
> <?php
> function test(boolean $param) {}
> test(true);
> ?>
> ```

> The above example will output:

> > Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to test() must be an instance of boolean, boolean given

So in a nutshell, `boolean` is an alias for `bool`, and aliases don't work in type hints.
Use the "real" name: **bool**

---

There are no similarity between [`Type Hinting`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) and [`Type Casting`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

*Type hinting* is something like that you are telling your function which type should be accepted.

*Type casting* is to "switching" between types.

> The casts allowed are:
>
> ```
> (int), (integer) - cast to integer
> (bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
> (float), (double), (real) - cast to float
> (string) - cast to string
> (array) - cast to array
> (object) - cast to object
> (unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)
> ```

In php *type casting* both (bool) and (boolean) are the same.

Comment: `no similarity between Type Hinting and Type Casting` -- A scalar type hint, both parameter and return type, does perform typecasting though. In other words: `(function():bool { return 1; })() === true`

Comment: Quite confusing, since `gettype()` returns `"boolean"` and not `"bool"`

Comment: @skerit: I'd assume that return value of `gettype()` cannot be fixed because of historical reasons and backwards compatibility. PHP is sadly full of this kind of weird edge cases because they want to avoid *any existing code from breaking* but still create new rules for code syntax written in the future.